# Wordpress 404 error podcast feed

Tags: wordpress, rss, podcast

When I try and validate my podcast feed I'm getting a 404 error. Can anyone shed some light on why? 
http://drlindatucker.com/dev/podcast-feed

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Now that you have set up your podcast website with WordPress, it is time to submit it to iTunes. Before submitting it to iTunes, you might want to check how your podcast will look in iTunes. To do this, launch iTunes and go to File » Subscribe to Podcast and enter your feed URL.

[step-by-step-guide-how-to-start-a-podcast-with-wordpress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/step-by-step-guide-how-to-start-a-podcast-with-wordpress/)

Comment: I did this. Neither of my 2 uploaded podcasts are showing up in iTunes, which is why I tried to validate the feed. That's when I found the 404 error.

Comment: The URL is an RSS feed in XML format.  Unlikely you will be able to open in a browser.  Regardless: "Upon submission, your podcast feed will be submitted to iTunes review queue. After approval by iTunes review staff, it will be added to iTunes directory and you will be notified via email."

Comment: It did not work. iTunes gave me a 404 error when I tried to submit it.

Comment: Where did you get the URL for the podcast feed?

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using http://drlindatucker.com/feed/ ? This seems to give a correct feed

Edit: Based on the website, I assumed that this was a a Wordpress powered site and the feed is usually /feed which I tried and could see the feed